# How to configure symfony project in local server?

Tags: symfony1

I am beginner for symfony. I have to configure the already developed project that is built using symfony. I changed the database information but when browse localhost/myproject/web there is nothing displayed. What can i do to configure the project in local server. I have created the database as well. Hope to get help. Thanks ..........

Answer (score 0):

you need to point apache to the web folder in your symfony project. or if your project reside inside apache web root you could use:

**http://localhost/myproject/web/index.php** but that won't show any errors. insted of that you could use:

http://localhost/myproject/web/**frontend**_dev.php where **frontend** is the name of front controler ( this file is in web/ folder).

and if then you don't get any output look into your apache server error log to find why project isn't working.

few resolves:

when in symfony project root execute this in command prompt:

```
php symfony cache:clear
php symfony fix-perms
```

and then try url above.

more info [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/tutorial/1_2/my-first-project)

Comment: Thanks deresh!! I tried to find the error log file in apache but i found no error log there. Also tried the second option but it did not work. I have changed the database info in file databases.yml of the folder config. Do i need to do anything from command prompt except database info change??

Comment: some additional info is needes: what os do you use ( win, linux, osx)? where is your apache installed? i need this info to know where the logs are

Comment: and version of symfony you use could help also. and for second option you need the right controler name ( it isn't always frontend) that you can find in projects web/ folder

Comment: Ya I'm using windows, my apache is in folder c:\wamp\apache, and the version of symfony is 1.0.9.

Comment: for symfony 1.0.x for clearing cache you should use: php symfony cc
error log should be in C:\wamp\apache\log