# Symfony project is not work on local pc

Tags: php, symfony1, local

I have this trouble: i copy symfony project files on my pc, after that change paths and db settings, and it still not working, even dont tell about errors! Maybe there is some specific actions for setting up symhony on another server? 
Almost the same problem [How to configure symfony project in local server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653760/how-to-configure-symfony-project-in-local-server) but when i try execute "php symfony" it prints "no such file or directory"

There are no any php errors at all.
Using Fedora 15 OS, and apache. php work in command line, symfony is not working. I tried to find  out what is happening - inside Controller.class some error, when it use processObjects method, it take 11 objects, and after first of them (header.object.php) it stops.

Comment: Are there any errors in PHP logs? We will need more information.

Comment: What OS are you using ? using apache ?

Answer (score 0):

The white screen generally means symfony can't write to cache and/or log dir, check on apache error logs to see details.

if 'php symfony' on command line throws no such file or directory could mean php is not in your system path.

Please add more information to get answers

Answer (score 0):

myabe, as said below is a permission problem of the caché and log files. Check if they are writable. Good Luck!